# how should i send the validation error messages received from webapi(server) to the views in mvc6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(CampaignModel model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var helper = new HttpClientHelper<CampaignModel>();
         var response = await helper.PostAsync(UriHelper.POST_Campaigns_Add, model);
     }
     else
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "");
         return View(model);
     }
     return RedirectToAction("List");
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertCampaigns([FromBody]CampaignDetailModel campaign)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         await _campaignService.InsertCampaign(campaign);
         return new ObjectResult(campaign.Id);
     }
     return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
}
```

Comment: please add what your code currently lacks so that people get an idea what you have done till now and what more you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

People have used HTTP response codes as a means to indicating what types of errors have occurred on the server.  200 OK would be success, whereas 401, 500, etc. could be used to indicate exception was thrown, the input was bad, etc.